# Data-Level Authorization (ASP.NET Core 2.2)

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

How can I use claim for data-level authorization?

For example,

- Project 1: User A, User B, User C
- Project 2: User B
- Project 3: User C

Meaning

- User A can only access Project 1
- User B can access both Project 1 and 2
- User C can access both Project 1 and 3

How do I implement the above logic?

Comment: Your question is not clear, What is project here? And here you can seek for help if you've done some efforts, not without showing some effort. Tell what you have tried and show some effort.

Comment: you need to create a relational database between the project and user who can access.

Comment: @Kaushik: Forgive me, I just started using ASP.NET Core for my project recently. The project objective is to help a company manage data consolidation. 

I have tried to create a table to join between the project and the user. 
User  - Id, Name, Designation, ...
Project - Id, Name, Description, Create Date ....
ProjectUser - UserId, ProjectId

My question is how can I restrict the user to only access the project which belongs to him/her. 

Meaning, the user can only see or access the project once he/she logs in.

Comment: @NishalK.R: Thanks bro, I already had that linked table. The problem is the coding. I really have no idea how to do it. Would you mind sharing me the link if u know any?

Comment: @Reach009 You can keep the OwnerId in your table and while fetching the results you filter for the user who is logged in. I doubt this as a solution but this can be way around.

Comment: @Kaushik: My main concern is the security part. How can I make sure that user can  only access his/her own project data? I understand the joining and query parts. I read some articles and they said need to add claim, but I do not understand.

Comment: @Reach009 The claim is generally used for the Role based access of the data. Here your problem is different. You don't have roles, you've user. see this article - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-mvc-using-cookie/

Comment: @Kaushik: thank you for clarifying. I have created a join table which connects user and project tables together. I got this idea to restrict the data access using model-builder in the application context. Somehow, do u know how can I pull projects which are related to the current user log in? 

My code:  
  modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasQueryFilter(x =>
                        x.Id == UserProject.FirstOrDefault(y => y.UserId == _userId).ProjectId);

Note: _userId = current user. From the code, I can only retrieve one project which is related to the user.

Comment: @Reach009 FirstOrDefault will give you the first matching record with the filter. Try using `select` so you'll be having full list.

Comment: @Kaushik: Still can not. I got an error because in my case,  I  am trying to compare the project Id, so when I use `select` ,  I can't refer to the projectId. 

Do you know any other ways to join the tables for this case? I already know the login user id. How can we join it in one shot? 

Thinking of something like this, but it does not work. 

**modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasQueryFilter(x =>
x.UserProject.SingleOrDefault(y => y.UserId == <useridfromclaims> && y.ProjectId == x.ProjectId) != null );**

Comment: @Reach First do `where` and then `select`.

Comment: @Kaushik:   **modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.Id == UserProject.Where(y => y.UserId == _userId).Select(y => y.ProjectId).ToList());**

got error '==' cannot be applied from type long to list long

Comment: @Reach009 why do you need initial  ` x.Id ==` ? What is output of `UserProject.Where(y => y.UserId == _userId).Select(y => y.ProjectId).ToList()`

Comment: @Kaushik I need x.Id to select the only the project Id that is/are found from the query and build the model. I just figured out the solution. I can use **contain** instead of '==' since the output is a list of project Id. Thanks man for quick response. 